# Using POST HTTP method to read data from Solr using SolrJ

Tags: java, solr, solrj

We are using the SolrJ client to query documents from Solr. The query that we are building is large and Solr is rejecting the query (with error response [`414 URI Too Long`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/414)).

However, I can directly call Solr's `/query` endpoint and post the query as the body using a POST request. Is there a way to do this using the SolrJ client?

Comment: Hi Amit, Did you find a solution using solrj? I am also having this problem for one of my scenario

Answer (score 5):

You can use post method in SolrJ using QueryRequest which has options to set HTTP methods.

```
public QueryResponse query(SolrQuery parameters){
        QueryResponse resp=null;
        try {
            QueryRequest queryRequest=new QueryRequest(parameters);
            queryRequest.setMethod(SolrRequest.METHOD.POST);
            NamedList nl=solrClient.request(queryRequest);
            resp=new QueryResponse(nl, solrClient);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resp;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you perform queries by instantiating a [`SolrQuery`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_2_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrQuery.html) and asking the [`SolrClient`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_2_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrClient.html) to execute it, you can simply pass the [HTTP method](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_2_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrRequest.METHOD.html) to use as an [additional](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_2_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrClient.html#query-org.apache.solr.common.params.SolrParams-org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.METHOD-) [parameter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_2_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrClient.html#query-java.lang.String-org.apache.solr.common.params.SolrParams-org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.METHOD-). Here is a quick example:

```java
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.METHOD;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;

/* ... */

HttpSolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient.
    Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr").
        withConnectionTimeout(1000).
        withSocketTimeout(60 * 1000).
        build();
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery("*:*");
QueryResponse response = client.query(query, METHOD.POST);
```